# How can I return the value that a StatefulWidget contains to use it in a ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem, it happens that I have a `StatefulWidget` with a method that returns a `ListView.builder`.

The `ListView.builder` that has a column with two children: `textField` and a `row` with two `radios`.

Radiobutons are built in another `StatefulWidget`, of this statefullwidget I'm interested in the value that has been selected, but I need this return value in my previous `StatefulWidget`.

I don't know if there is a way for a `StatefulWidget` wigdet in addition to returning a widget to return another value, please help me.

Here is the ListView.builder:

```dart
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: preguntas.secciones[0].preguntas.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
      final pregunta = questionsList[i];
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(pregunta.descripcion,
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "OpenSans-Bold")),
          RadioButtom(),
          TextFormField(
            enabled:
                (!_radioValue && pregunta.respuestas[0].pregunta.obligatoria)
                    ? false
                    : true,
            validator: (value) {
              if (pregunta.respuestas[0].pregunta.obligatoria == true &&
                  value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Por favor ingrese texto';
              }
              return null;
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintMaxLines: 500,
              hintText: pregunta.respuestas[0].pregunta.descripcion,
              hintStyle:
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular", fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              preguntasGlobal = preguntas;
              // preguntasGlobal[i].respuestas[0].comentario = value;
              // preguntasGlobal[i].respuestas[0].respuesta = true;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0)
        ],
      );
    },
  );
```

Here is the RadioButtom StatefulWidget

```dart
class RadioButtom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioButtomState createState() => _RadioButtomState();
}

class _RadioButtomState extends State<RadioButtom> {
  bool _radioValue =
      false; //se usa como estado y tambien para mantener el valor del radiobuttom seleccionado
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Radio(
            value: true,
            groupValue: _radioValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _radioValue = value;
              });
            }),
        Text(
          'Yes',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular",
          ),
        ),
        Radio(
            value: false,
            groupValue: _radioValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _radioValue = value;
              });
            }),
        Text(
          'No',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular",
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lift the state up. Instead of storing the states in `RadioButtom`, you store the state in the widget that contains the `ListView`, say `ListViewBuilder`.

1. Change the constructor of your `RadioButtom` to accept a value and a callback

```dart
class RadioButtom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioButtomState createState() => _RadioButtomState();

  RadioButtom({this.value, this.onChanged});

  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
}
```

2. Use the field in your `State`

```dart
Radio(
  value: true,
  groupValue: widget.value,
  onChanged: widget.onChanged,
),
```

3. Store your state in `ListViewBuilder`

```dart
// For example
List<bool> _answers = []; // Initialize it with number of elements you need
```

4. Use it in your `itemBuilder`

```dart
RadioButtom(
  value: _answers[i],
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _answers[i] = value;
    });
  }),
),
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer, but I have a problem, if I put the setState in my list.builder, when I choose an option from the radioButtom it automatically refreshes the screen and no option is visibly marked. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/356ff51ff4f080d20e2afbe66b3c28d3 take a look at this example here. If it refreshes your screen, you'd then have to find out what other components in your widget is causing it.

Comment: I thank you very much for your time and kindness, your help has served me well. Another way that I found to solve my problem was to use Function (x) that helped me to get the Radiobuttom to communicate with my ListView.builder.